# Custom Button onClickListener is static context?

Tags: android, button

I have an activity that creates a custom button. 
Here is the button class.

In my main activity I have methods that allow the program to jump between activities, but the error I am getting is that I am referencing a non static method from a static context. Why is that? Isnt the button a new instance?

```
public class LoginButton extends Button {

private DataAdapter myDataAdapter;

private String LOG_TAG = "Login Button";

private EditText myPasswordEditText;
private EditText myUserEditText;

Context ctx;


public LoginButton(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(ctx, attrs);

    this.ctx = ctx;

    setOnClickListener(clicker);
    myDataAdapter = new DataAdapter(ctx);
}


//Other way is to implement the OnClickListener and implement the onClick method.
OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(CheckUsernameField() && CheckPasswordField()){

            myDataAdapter.open();

            if(myDataAdapter.LoginToDB(myUserEditText.getText().toString(), myPasswordEditText.getText().toString())){

                //TODO: Custom buttons have trouble getting context. My solution was to call different activities from static method, but that requires setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK which is not recommended.
                MainActivity.GoToBeginRunScreen(ctx);
                CreateAlertDialog("Login successful");
            }
            else
                CreateAlertDialog("Invalid username and password");

            myDataAdapter.close();

        }
        else
            CreateAlertDialog("Please enter a username and password");

    }
};
```

Here is the code I am calling from the above button.

```
public void GoToBeginRunScreen(Context ctx){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, BeginRunActivity.class);
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: the error is happeneing at MainActivity.GoToBeginRunScreen(ctx);

Comment: how can you access GoToBeginRunScreen directly it is neither static

Comment: (( MainActivity)ctx).GoToBeginRunScreen(ctx);  do this

Comment: Pavan. That works.
Can you put that as the answer with an explanation of why it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access non static methods directly by class you have to create class instance in this case you have to use class (activity) current instance using Context so just put

```
(( MainActivity)ctx).GoToBeginRunScreen(ctx);
```

in simple way in your requirement you can directly call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, BeginRunActivity.class);
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

in your click listener because you holding context

Comment: Wow. I cant believe I didnt think about this. 
With that explanation, its obvious to me now.

Comment: So (MainActivity) is specifying the MainActivity ctx?

Comment: @Spectrem see edit may be it better you directly call there if only requirement is calling new activity

Comment: yes if you calling this from only MainActivity then its belongs to that if you also calling from another then that will instance of calling activity